# Сомнительно выглядит сообщение о новом знаке по метке

Tags: дефект, дизайн, знаки, профиль-участника

Хотя практически всё пространство пустое, футер блока почему-то накладывается на табы:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: На компьютере??

Comment: @alexolut, держи баг: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8050/178988

Comment: @VerNick, да на компьютере.

Comment: @Qwertiy Поправьте `мшку` на `мышку` на вопрос куда идет ссылка

Comment: @VerNick, да уже заметил, но всё равно спасибо)

Comment: Аналогичные вопросы на англометах: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316061/youve-earned-badge-panel-layouts-are-broken  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374744/buggy-ui-when-a-badge-is-earned