# Неверный тултип у числа отклонённых тревог

Tags: дефект, локализация, тревоги, инструменты-модератора

Если навести мышку на число в скобках

[image: скриншот тултипа]

то показывается надпись

> Общее количество сигналов тревоги, которые не были отмечены полезными

что, на мой взгляд, означает отклонённые и спорные.

Однако, если зайти в тревоги, то видно, что эта единица - это число отклонённых тревог, а 7 спорных вообще нигде не участвуют, как, похоже, и тревоги на комментариях (168 + 65 = 233):

[image: скриншот тревог]

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, разве это инструменты модератора?

Comment: У обычных участников такого пункта нет. Уже как КМ становитесь, бронзовеете...

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, даже для собственной учётки?

Comment: Особенно для [собственных](https://i.stack.imgur.com/101Vz.png)!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, внезапно. Ведь эта информация всё равно есть по ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

[Исходная строка](https://ru.traducir.win/string/7827) имеет такой вид:

> Total number of raised flags marked unhelpful

Вероятно, под "unhelpful" в данном случае подразумевается не множество, обратное "полезным", а просто однозначно отклонённые тревоги. Например, есть старинный вопрос [Only show unhelpful flags when clicking unhelpful flag count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168107/339911) о предложении поправить ссылки в окошке тревог, и там (англоязычный) автор вполне чётко пишет о том, что приходится искать именно "отклонённые" тревоги:

> You have to search for "Declined"...

К самой формулировке вопросов у него не возникло. Поэтому я предлагаю просто поправить наш перевод, чтобы "unhelpful" переводился как "отклонённые" для минимизации разночтений.

Comment: _"marked unhelpful"_ != "not marked helpful", так что предлагаю перевод всё-таки поменять.

Comment: @Qwertiy уже поменян. См. актуальную версию по первой ссылке в ответе.

Comment: @Qwertiy кстати, традусёр иногда глючит и показывает какую-то кешированную версию перевода, хотя в его же базе уже другая строка находится. Так что не верь своим глазам :)