# Артефакт верстки на странице пользователя

Tags: дефект, дизайн, профиль-участника

Description:

1. Открыть страницу https://ru.stackoverflow.com
2. Авторизоваться
3. Перейти на страницу своего профиля
4. Перейти на вкладку "Активность"
5. Подвести курсор мыши к одной из вкладок "Репутация", "все действия",
   "реакции", "голоса"

Actual result: Фон становится прозрачным и текст вкладки тяжело читаем.

Expected result: Изменения фона не ведут к проблеме удобочитаемости названия вкладки.

OS: Windows 7x64
Browser: GChrome (latest version)

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Не совсем, хотя описанная мною проблема скорее всего возникла из-за этого. Будет видно, когда пофиксят.

Answer (score 0):

Для затемнения белого фона используется

```
background-color: rgba(132,141,149,0.05);
```

поэтому это автоматически исправляется вместе с блоком меток из соседнего [вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8049/178988).